# SQL INSERT doens't insert, without any error

Tags: php, html, sql

I am making a hotel booking system for a school project. 
Guests first need to create an account:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$signupdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['signupdate']);
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

$hoteluserkey = uniqid('', true);

//Error handlers
//Check for empty fields
if (empty($signupdate) || empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($address) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?signup=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    //Check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=invalid");
        exit();
    } else {
        //Check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?signup=invalidemail");
            exit();
        } else {
                //Hashing the password
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //Insert the user into the database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO hotelusers 
                    (hotelusers_signupdate, hotelusers_hoteluserkey, hotelusers_first, hotelusers_last, hotelusers_email, hotelusers_phone, hotelusers_address, hotelusers_pwd) 
                    VALUES ('$signupdate', '$hoteluserkey', '$first', '$last', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$hashedPwd');"; 
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit();
}
```

This code works.
Now to problem comes. When someone books a room they see these input fields:

```
<div class="book">
    <p class="main_p_ex">Book a room</p>
    <form class="book" action="includes/book.inc.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="bookdate" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"); ?>">

        <input type="text" name="userkey" placeholder="your key">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
        <p>room</p>
        <select name="room">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
            <option value="5">five</option>
            <option value="6">six</option>
            <option value="7">seven</option>
            <option value="8">eight</option>
            <option value="9">nine</option>
            <option value="10">ten</option>
        </select>

        <p>from</p>
        <input type="date" name="from" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
        <p>to</p>
        <input type="date" name="to" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">

        <textarea name="otherguests" placeholder="full names of all other 
              guests"></textarea>
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="any comments?"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Book!</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

This also works fine. 
I have this code for inserting these inputs into a database:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$bookdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bookdate']);
$userkey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userkey']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['room']);
$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['from']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['to']);
$otherguests = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherguests']);
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['comments']);

$bookingkey = uniqid('', true);

//Error handlers
//Check if inputs are empty
if (empty($userkey) || empty($pwd) || empty($room) || empty($from) || empty($to) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotelusers WHERE hotelusers_hoteluserkey='$userkey'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?key=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing the password
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['hotelusers_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?key=error");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true){

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotelrooms WHERE hotelrooms_id='$room'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $roomnew = $row['hotelrooms_name'];         }
                }

                $fromnew = strtotime($from);
                $tonew = strtotime($to);
                $datediff = $tonew - $fromnew;
                $days = round($datediff / 86400);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotelrooms WHERE hotelrooms_id='$room'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $pricepd = $row['hotelrooms_price'];        }
                }

                $price = $days * $pricepd;

                echo $roomnew . " -- " . $price  . " -- " . $days . " -- " . $bookdate . " -- " . $userkey . " -- " . $room . " -- " . $otherguests . " -- " . $comments;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO hotelbookings 
                    (hotelbooking_bookingkey, hotelbooking_bookdate, hotelbooking_userkey, hotelbooking_room, hotelbooking_from, hotelbooking_to, hotelbooking_days, hotelbooking_price, hotelbooking_paid, hotelbooking_otherguests, hotelbooking_comments) 
                    VALUES ('$bookingkey', '$bookdate', '$userkey', '$roomnew', '$from', '$to', '$days', '$price', '$otherguests', '$comments');";  
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                //header("Location: ../index.php?booking=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}   
}   else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?booking=error");
    exit();
}
```

NOTE: I disabled the last header function for debugging. Un-commenting it changes nothing. Also tried clearing browser history, cookies and all that. Nothing works.

What am I missing here?

I don't get any errors, and the `echo $roomnew . " -- " . $price  . " -- " . $days . " -- " . $bookdate . " -- " . $userkey . " -- " . $room . " -- " . $otherguests . " -- " . $comments;` works fine. It just doesn't insert anything.

Comment: Just a quick thought, are you ever committing the transaction? `$mysqli->commit()`. Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: Hey friend. I see you're using mysqli, you should know that `mysqli_real_escape_string` isn't really that *safe* and you should opt for using [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I've noticed in your insert statement you are wanting to insert into 11 columns but you actually only set 10 values. Maybe it's worth looking into that? Failing that, double check by outputting your [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) so that we can help you better. You could (since you're not using prepare) just `echo $sql` and post that query into your favorite database management tool

Comment: @IsThisJavascript thanks for helping. I resolved the issue by just dropping the entire table and making a new one, also wrote the entire php again. It works now, didn't even change anything... but thanks nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself by just making everything again... kinda weird I know

Comment: What's different ?

Comment: @blackandorangecat Don't even know haha